# Running a @BeforeMethod testNG annotation when the method *contains* a group

Tags: java, testng, integration-testing

If I have a beforeMethod with a group, and I run a different group, but within that group there exists a test that has both the group that I'm running as well as the group with the beforeMethod, I want that test to run its beforemethod. So for example:

```
@BeforeMethod(groups = "a")
public void setupForGroupA() {
...
}

@Test(groups = {"supplemental", "a"})
public void test() {
...
}
```

when I run testNG with groups=supplemental, I still want the beforeMethod to run before test, but because the group is supplemental instead of 'a', it won't.

This seems like such an obvious feature to me that I feel like I must be using the groups incorrectly, so I would also like to explain my workflow as well, in case that's where my issue is.

I'm using groups to define different layers of tests, as well as whether they need their own account to be created or if they need to use a proxy to access their data, etc. I'll have groups of smoke, supplemental and regression as well as groups of uniqueAccount, proxy, etc. I don't need specific setup for the first groupings, but those are the groups I pass in to run in maven. I require specific setups for the latter groups, but I never want to run just the tests that require a proxy, or require a unique account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups configuration is not evaluated at runtime. `test` method won't activate `setupForGroupA` method.

The feature is used to find methods you want to run. 
According to the following example:

```
@BeforeMethod(groups = "a")
public void setupForGroupA() {
...
}

@Test(groups = {"supplemental", "a"})
public void test() {
...
}

@Test(groups = {"supplemental"})
public void test2() {
...
}
```

If you run this class with group "a" it will run `setupForGroupA` and `test` methods because they are marked with the group "a".

If you run this class with group "supplemental" it will run `test` and `test2` methods because they are marked with the group "supplemental".

It looks you have different behavior for some methods, so a good approach is to separate methods in different classes and select tests by class instead of select tests by groups.

```
public class A {
  @BeforeMethod
  public void setupForGroupA() {
    ...
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    ...
  }
}
```

and

```
public class Supplemental {
  @Test
  public void test2() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Running class A will run `setupForGroupA` and `test` only.
Running class Supplemental will run `test2` only.
Running both classes will run everything.

In case you want to run both classes and filter by something else, you can implement your own logic with [a method interceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors):

```
@MyCustomAnnotation(tags = "a", "supplemental")
public class A {
  ...
}

@MyCustomAnnotation(tags = "supplemental")
public class Supplemental {
  ...
}

public class MyInterceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {

  public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
    // for each method, if its class contains the expected tag, then add it to the list
    // expect tag can be passed by a system property or in a parameter from the suite file (available from ITestContext)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get it correct, you want to run your before method every time. In this case, you could set alwaysRun=true for your before method like this-

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true, groups = "a")
public void setupForGroupA() {
...
}
```

This one of the solutions you want.

Comment: So to expand the example a bit I could add another method 'test2' with group supplemental, but no group 'a'. In this case I would want the before method to run before 'test' but not before 'test2'.